# QML: update item of QSortFilterProxyModel when source item changed

Tags: qt, model, filter, delegates, qml

I have model derived from QAbstractListModel and it's a source of filter proxy derived from QSortFilterProxyModel. Filter proxy used as model in TableView at QML.
So, if something changes in initial model, proxy automatically resortes and updates all delegated (even if delegate doesn't need update). So, I disable property dynamicSortFilter of proxy. Now, delegates not update even if needed. So, I can make connection to model and detect signal **dataChanged** inside delegate. But how to update this delegate after this?

Comment: Why disable the dynamicSortFilter?